# Nginx Proxy_pass redirect chain

Tags: nginx, iframe, server, reverse-proxy

I'm working on a project for a small store and I need to aggregate several websites in a single monitor. In order to do that I'm using iframes.

One of those iframed sites (A tire factory) is using x-frame-options-same-origin and depending upon the user clicks it may redirect to another domain with an also x-frame set to same-origin.

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy + proxy_hide_header to work around the first iframed page.

How can I also hide the second page (the redirected one) x-frame-option header?

Thanks, have a great day!

```
server { 
       listen 80;
       server_name example.com;
       location / {
                   proxy_pass http://iframed1.com;
                   proxy_hide_header X-frame-Options;
                   }
       }
```